# How to assert multiple method calls with different parameters each time in python unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I am using python unittest to test my code. As part of my code, I am using these

```
boto3.client('sts')
boto3.client('ec2')
boto3.client('ssm', arg1, arg2)
```

So I mocked boto3 before writing my test case, and taking it as argument.
Now I can assert whether boto3.client called or not.

But I want to check whehter boto3.client called with sts and boto3.client called wit ec2 and with ssm,arg1,arg2.

When there is only one call I was able to do using `boto3.client.assert_called_with('my parameters')`. But facing issue to check multiple calls with different parameters each time.

```
@patch('createCustomer.src.main.boto3')
    def test_my_code(self, mock_boto3):
        # Executing main class
        mainclass(arg1, arg2)
        # Verifing
        mock_boto3.client.assert_called()
```

I want to achieve like

```
mock_boto3.client.assert_called_once_with('sts')
mock_boto3.client.assert_called_once_with('ec2')
mock_boto3.client.assert_called_once_with('ssm',arg1,arg2)
```

But this is giving error in first assert only, saying boto3.client called 3 times and parameters it is showing of last call i.e. 'ssm', arg1, arg2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to verify multiple calls to the same mock, you can use [`assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) with [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call). In your case:

```
mock_boto3.client.assert_has_calls([
    call('sts'),
    call('ec2'),
    call('ssm', arg1, arg2)
])
```

Comment: is this `call` is part of syntax? If I am writing call('sts'), it is giving syntax error, unresolved reference to call / name call is not defined. But when I check has_calls expected parameters it contains call('st's)

Comment: @venkat do you mean a *Name*Error? Like `patch`, `call` is part of `unittest.mock`; you'll have to `import` it from that module similarly.

Comment: ohh! got it. I did, `from unittest.mock import call` and it worked. Previously I am just importing patch and MagicMock